# Displaying NSTimer value on label

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

There is a button and a label in my project.After clicking the button i need to start a `NSTimer` which displays it's value on label.For example 1sec.I am not sure whether timer returns value.is there any other way to do this?.

Comment: You can refer this [Tutorial](http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-create-countdown-timer-in-iphone.html) it will help you

Comment: thanks for your tutorial

Comment: @thavasidurai : you should not just pass a link. Instead you can give your answer, please read FAQ. am not down-voting but, someone may.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thank you. i will correct it from next time onwards

Comment: You can update it even now :) You are the first one to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

in the function of button click

```
{
      NSTimer *t;
      t=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

in showTimer function

```
-(void)showTimer{
    static int i=0;
    static int min=0;

    if(i>=59){
        i=0;
        min++;
    } else {
        i++;
    }

    yourLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d:%d ",min,i];
}
```

Comment: You method in wrong... please correct before someone downvotes you.

Comment: how can i make mistake on that. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:(1) target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runner addTimer:aTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; 
int i=0;

    - (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer 
    {

    if(condition)
    {
    // timer repeat
    // your actions
     i++;
        int conseconds = i % 60; 
        int conminutes = (i / 60) % 60; 

        timelable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", conminutes,conseconds];
    [theTimer isValid];
    }
    else
    {
    // your actions
    //timer stopped
    [theTimer invalidate];
    }
    }
```

Comment: i value increase every seconds

Comment: please format your code and why is 60? all minutes dont have 60 seconds at all. Yes all minutes dont have 60 seconds :)

Comment: timer increase  i one by one,it only get number not in time format so use to convert option in this code